# What does -t option in cmake --build?

Tags: cmake, cmakelists-options

I have some question about Cmake options.

1. What does it mean of `cmake --build . -j -t label_image`? I wonder what `-t` option means.
2. Is it same `cmake ./ -DTFLITE_ENABLE_GPU=ON` with `set($TFLITE_ENABLE_GPU ON)`? In other words, is the option value of cmake same with the value defined by `set` function in CmakeLists.txt?

Comment: Did you already checked the CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html?highlight=build#build-a-project) for the first part of your question?

Comment: Please, ask a **single question** in a **question post**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With `-t <tgt>` or `--target <tgt>` you tell cmake to build only the target `<tgt>` instead of the `all` target, see [the CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html?#build-a-project):

> `--target <tgt>...`, `-t <tgt>...`
>
> Build  instead of the default target. Multiple targets may be given, separated by spaces.

2. The alternatives are not the same, even though you may see similar effects in certain scenarios. (I assume the `$` in the cmake command to be a typo; otherwise you're not even working with variables of the same name, since the cmake variable name contains the dollar char.)

```
set(TFLITE_ENABLE_GPU ON)
```

Sets a cmake variable. The value of the variable can only be seen in the current scope and descendant scopes. The value won't be visible before this command and it is not available in the parent directory.

```
cmake  -DTFLITE_ENABLE_GPU=ON .
```

on the other hand (re)configures a project in the given directory setting the `TFLITE_ENABLE_GPU` cache variable to `ON`. This value is set before cmake starts parsing the `CMakeLists.txt` files and it is persisted across reconfigurations.

You could e.g. observe the difference, if you add the following logic to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
message("(1) FOO = ${FOO}; CACHE{FOO} = $CACHE{FOO}; BAR = ${BAR}")

function(test_funct) # functions introduce a new scope
    set(FOO BAR)
    message("(2) FOO = ${FOO}; CACHE{FOO} = $CACHE{FOO}")
function()

test_funct()

message("(3) FOO = ${FOO}; CACHE{FOO} = $CACHE{FOO}")
set(FOO BAZ)

function(test_funct2) # functions introduce a new scope
    message("(4) FOO = ${FOO}; CACHE{FOO} = $CACHE{FOO}")
    set(FOO FOOBAR)
    message("(5) FOO = ${FOO}; CACHE{FOO} = $CACHE{FOO}")
function()

test_funct2()
message("(6) FOO = ${FOO}; CACHE{FOO} = $CACHE{FOO}")
set(FOO 99 CACHE STRING "")
message("(7) FOO = ${FOO}; CACHE{FOO} = $CACHE{FOO}")
```

Output of

```
cmake -D FOO=42 -S source_dir -B build_dir
```

```
(1) FOO = 42; CACHE{FOO} = 42; BAR = 
(2) FOO = BAR; CACHE{FOO} = 42
(3) FOO = 42; CACHE{FOO} = 42
(4) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 42
(5) FOO = FOOBAR; CACHE{FOO} = 42
(6) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 42
(7) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 42
```

Output when running

```
cmake build_dir
```

after running the command above.

```
(1) FOO = 42; CACHE{FOO} = 42; BAR = 
(2) FOO = BAR; CACHE{FOO} = 42
(3) FOO = 42; CACHE{FOO} = 42
(4) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 42
(5) FOO = FOOBAR; CACHE{FOO} = 42
(6) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 42
(7) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 42
```

Value when running

```
cmake -D FOO=44 build_dir
```

```
(1) FOO = 44; CACHE{FOO} = 44; BAR = 
(2) FOO = BAR; CACHE{FOO} = 44
(3) FOO = 44; CACHE{FOO} = 44
(4) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 44
(5) FOO = FOOBAR; CACHE{FOO} = 44
(6) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 44
(7) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 44
```

When running

```
cmake -U FOO build_dir
```

to clear the cache entry, we'll get

```
(1) FOO = ; CACHE{FOO} = ; BAR = 
(2) FOO = BAR; CACHE{FOO} = 
(3) FOO = ; CACHE{FOO} = 
(4) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 
(5) FOO = FOOBAR; CACHE{FOO} = 
(6) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 
(7) FOO = BAZ; CACHE{FOO} = 99
```

Value when removing the cache variable when reconfiguring.